# Unable to install Libgfortran4 in a Docker File

Tags: apt, 18.04, docker

I'm trying to install Libgfortran in Docker but I have this error when I build the file:

```
E: Unable to locate package libgfortran4
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y libgfortran4' returned a non-zero code: 100
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build : Build failed
```

The docker config is below

```
FROM python:3.9-slim
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
ADD requirements.txt ./requirements.txt 
COPY  pyglow-0.0.0-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl ./pyglow-0.0.0-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl

RUN apt-get clean && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    g++ \
    gcc \
    tzdata \
        libgeos-dev  \
        libproj-dev \ 
    proj-data \
    proj-bin \
        gfortran \
        software-properties-common 

RUN add-apt-repository main
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libgfortran4

COPY . /app/
```

I have tried to download and install packages .deb but every time it requests more .deb files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change the first line of Dockerfile from `FROM python:3.9-slim` to   `FROM python:3.9-slim-buster` to use Debian Buster as package base. Only this version of Debian provides [*libgfortran4* package](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libgfortran4).